# What happens if I use a Windows registration code twice?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-10-upgrade, windows-11-upgrade

The situation:

- Computer A runs Windows 10 with a registration code originating from Windows 7
- Computer B runs Windows 10 with a registration code originating from Windows 7

Thus both installations got issued identical generic registration codes during the activation process, so I can't readout the original registration codes anymore with the help of dedicated tools (been there, tried that)

Now I'm about to do a hardware change on computer B and want make a complete fresh installation using Windows 10 or (preferably) Windows 11.

[The old upgrade path is now closed](https://borncity.com/win/2023/09/29/windows-10-11-upgrade-path-with-windows-7-and-windows-8-1-keys-no-longer-works-sept-2023/), but from what I understand my old Windows 7 registration codes are still eligable for a fresh install of Windows 10/11 since they were once linked to the generic codes on the Microsoft activation servers when doing the Windows 10 installs - correct me, if I'm wrong.

My question is now:
what happens if I accidentally activate the new Windows 10/11 installation on computer B with the code that's still in use on computer A? Might both get blacklisted? Or is there a chance to swap both in that case?

Comment: Windows 7 to 10/11 upgrades no longer work, but if have a local account and convert that to a microsoft account and reboot at least once, the hardware id/product code should be embedded in your microsoft account. If you already use a microsoft account, this should already be the case, unless the ms account for computer B is different than A. Not sure how that's gonna work. With this set, do a new install of Windows 10 and when it asks for a key, skip. During sign in, sign in with your microsoft account, and it should activate by itself.

Comment: One other thing.  Registration is to keep honest people honest (which I implore).  Registration problems can be directed to Microsoft and 9/10, they will help you get past this.  They are looking for hackers/key distributors and not honest paying customers.  I suggest you call [Microsoft Activation Support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/licensing/existing-customer/activation-centers) and you will find them to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thus both installations got issued identical generic registration codes during the activation process, so I can't readout the original registration codes anymore with the help of dedicated tools (been there, tried that)

This is perfectly normal. Every system that was upgraded to Windows 10 from a previous eligible version of Windows got the same edition specific generic Windows 10 license.

It cannot be used to install Windows 10 or Windows 11, but due to the digital entitlement linked to the machine, it’s also unnecessary to input a license code while installing Windows 10 or Windows 11

> Now I'm about to do a hardware change on computer B and want make a complete fresh installation using Windows 10 or (preferably) Windows 11.

Unless you are talking about the motherboard, which is forever linked to the OEM license, this should not be an issue.

> The old upgrade path is now closed, but from what I understand my old Windows 7 registration codes are still eligable for a fresh install of Windows 10/11 since they were once linked to the generic codes on the Microsoft activation servers when doing the Windows 10 installs - correct me, if I'm wrong

The generic license key you have cannot be used to install any version of Windows. Furthermore, Windows 10 stop accepting Windows 7 licenses during the installation process, over a year ago.  Of course due to the permanent digital entitlement, it’s unnecessary to enter a license key to install Windows 10 on your systems.

> My question is now: what happens if I accidentally activate the new Windows 10/11 installation on computer B with the code that's still in use on computer A? Might both get blacklisted? Or is there a chance to swap both in that case?

You cannot accidentally activate a Windows system. License keys are not blacklisted. Digital entitlements cannot be transferred to another system. Windows 7 keys, today, cannot be used to install Windows 10 or Windows 11. OEM Windows 7 licenses cannot be transferred to new systems. Digital entitlement for each of your systems is permanent and independent of one another and cannot be revoked but can also not be transferred to another system.

You can simply install Windows 10 on these systems then upgrade to Windows 11 provided they are running supported hardware.